# Consuming https webservice with .pfx certificate in netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, https, pfx

I have a .pfx certificate from a client am supposed to consume his service. Each time i try to consume the service in my java application, my netbeans gives me an error 403 telling me to check the wsdl file or if the server is running. Please can anyone give me steps on how to consume this service without getting this error? Am using tomcat 6.0.29 and netbeans 6.9